# CSV to XML converter using Groovy

Tags: xml, csv, groovy

I am at the end of my ability with what i am trying to achieve here, i need to create a converter using groovy to convert CSV to XML.
My ability is very limited with groovy so the following code may be a pile of rubbish but it was put together using other pieces of code i have found.

```
package com.ns.extension.tee;

import com.ns.argo.business.api.ArgoUtils
import com.ns.argo.business.api.GroovyApi
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.jdom.Document
import org.jdom.Element

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
import javax.xml.transform.Result
import javax.xml.transform.Source
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult

/**
* Converting CSV to XML.
*
* * Date: 24/01/14 : 11:50
* Called from: Groovy Job.
*/
public class CSVtoXML extends GroovyApi {

/**
* Triggered from a Groovy Job.
* @param param
*/
public void execute(Map param) {
LOGGER.warn(String.format("At start of %s at %s", this.getClass().getName(), ArgoUtils.timeNow()));
convertCSVToXML();
LOGGER.warn(String.format("At end of %s at %s", this.getClass().getName(), ArgoUtils.timeNow()));
}

/**
* Loads and converts a file from CSV to XML.
*/
private void convertCSVToXML() {
List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>(5);

String path = "C:\\convert\\";
path = path.replaceAll("\\", "/");
File file = new File(path, "CRR.csv");
BufferedReader reader = null;

try {

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document newDoc = domBuilder.newDocument() as Document;
// Root element
Element rootElement = newDoc.createElement("XMLCreators");
newDoc.appendChild(rootElement);

reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
int line = 0;

String text = null;
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text, " ", false);
String[] rowValues = new String[st.countTokens()];
int index = 0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

  String next = st.nextToken();
  rowValues[index++] = next;

}

//String[] rowValues = text.split(",");

if (line == 0) { // Header row
  for (String col : rowValues) {
    headers.add(col);
  }
} else { // Data row
  Element rowElement = newDoc.createElement("row");
  rootElement.appendChild(rowElement);
  for (int col = 0; col < headers.size(); col++) {
    String header = headers.get(col);
    String value = null;

    if (col < rowValues.length) {
      value = rowValues[col];
    } else {
      // ?? Default value
      value = "";
    }

    Element curElement = newDoc.createElement(header);
    curElement.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(value));
    rowElement.appendChild(curElement);
  }
}
line++;
}

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

try {
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
osw = new OutputStreamWriter(baos);

TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
aTransformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

Source src = new DOMSource(newDoc);
Result result = new StreamResult(osw);
aTransformer.transform(src, result);

osw.flush();
System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
} catch (Exception exp) {
exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
try {
  osw.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
try {
  baos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CSVtoXML.class);
}
```

I would like it output in the follwoing format, all be it with different values this is just an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLCreators>
<row>
<Name>chi</Name>
<Age>23</Age>
<sex></sex>
</row>
<row>
<Name>kay</Name>
<Age>19</Age>
<sex>male</sex>
</row>
<row>
<Name>john</Name>
<Age></Age>
<sex>male</sex>
 </row>
 </XMLCreators>
```

Example CSV:

```
Job         Type        Cntr Number     Date            Booking Ref     Commodity   Weight      Special Instructions
JOB0001     Circle      12              31/09/2013      Book0001        1           100.00      Carry
JOB0002     Square      13              31/11/2013      Book0001        2           200.00      None
JOB0003     Cube        15              31-Dec-13       Book0001        3           300.00      Hide
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**03/02/2014 Current code**

```
package com.ns.extension.tee;

import com.ns.argo.business.api.ArgoUtils
import com.ns.argo.business.api.GroovyApi
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv
import groovy.xml.*
import org.apache.xalan.*

/**
 * Converting CSV to XML.
 * Date: 24/01/14 : 11:50
 * Called from: Groovy Job.
 */
public class CSVtoXML extends GroovyApi {

    public void execute(Map param) {
        new File( 'C:/convert/CRR_output.xml' ).withWriter { w ->
            new File( 'C:/convert/CRR.csv' ).withReader { r ->
                def csvParser = parseCsv( r , speerator: ',')
                w.println new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
                    XMLCreators {
                        csvParser.each { line ->
                            println line
                            if( line ['Job'] ){
                                row {
                                    job( line[ 'Job' ] )
                                    type( line[ 'Type' ] )
                                    cntr( line[ 'Cntr Number' ] )
                                    date( line[ 'Date' ] )
                                    bref( line[ 'Booking Ref' ] )
                                    comm( line[ 'Commodity' ] )
                                    weig( line[ 'Weight' ] )
                                    spci( line[ 'Special Instructions' ] )
                                }
                            }}
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    static main( args ) {
        new CSVtoXML().execute( [:] )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a 3 line example CSV?

Comment: Added to bottom of original post..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, assuming the example CSV you put in the question is in a file called `"mycsv.csv"`, you can do this:

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv
import groovy.xml.*

println XmlUtil.serialize( new File( 'mycsv.csv' ).withReader { r ->
    def csvParser = parseCsv( r, separator:'\t' )
    new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        XMLCreators {
            csvParser.each { line ->
                row {
                    job( line[ 'Job' ] )
                    type( line[ 'Type' ] )
                    cntr( line[ 'Cntr Number' ] )
                }
            }
        }
    }
} )
```

Which prints out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><XMLCreators>
  <row>
    <job>JOB0001</job>
    <type>Circle</type>
    <cntr>12</cntr>
  </row>
  <row>
    <job>JOB0002</job>
    <type>Square</type>
    <cntr>13</cntr>
  </row>
  <row>
    <job>JOB0003</job>
    <type>Cube</type>
    <cntr>15</cntr>
  </row>
</XMLCreators>
```

If you can't do the `@Grab` and you just need the jars to add to your classpath, then the main groovycsv jar (and its dependencies) [are listed here](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv/#getting-groovycsv)

#### Edit, formatting in the class structure you detail above:

```
package com.navis.extension.tee;

import com.navis.argo.business.api.ArgoUtils
import com.navis.argo.business.api.GroovyApi
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv
import groovy.xml.*

/**
 * Converting CSV to XML.
 *
 * * Date: 24/01/14 : 11:50
 * Called from: Groovy Job.
 */
public class CSVtoXML extends GroovyApi {
    public void execute(Map param) {
       new File( 'C:/convert/CRR_output.xml' ).withWriter { w ->
            new File( 'C:/convert/CRR.csv' ).withReader { r ->
                def csvParser = parseCsv( r , separator: ',')
                String xml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
                    XMLCreators {
                        csvParser.each { line ->
                            println line
                            if( line.size() ) {
                                row {
                                    job( line[ 'Job' ] )
                                    type( line[ 'Type' ] )
                                    cntr( line[ 'Cntr Number' ] )
                                    date( line[ 'Date' ] )
                                    bref( line[ 'Booking Ref' ] )
                                    comm( line[ 'Commodity' ] )
                                    weig( line[ 'Weight' ] )
                                    spci( line[ 'Special Instructions' ] )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                w.writeLine( xml )
            }
        }
    }
    static main( args ) {
        new CSVtoXML().execute( [:] )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I have copied the code into intelliJ and tried to run it, dont get anything in the run screen at the bottom, where do i put the file? there is no location specified in the code, doi need to put the code above inside my code or just run it on its own? also have a 'cannot resolve symbol xlson' and also getting ''serialize' in 'groovy.xml.xmlutil' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.object)'' errors.

Hope that made sense, thanks for you help so far, i am massvily struggling with this.

Comment: Does the code work if you run it in the Groovy console?  The file looks like it should be `new File( 'C:/convert/CRR.csv' )` (from looking at the code you posted)...  Right... I have taken your original class and put my code into it.  THis currently prints the xml, but I guess it should go somewhere instead?

Comment: You'll need to make sure you have the dependencies I linked to on your class path or add `com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0` to your mavan/gradle build script as a compile time dependency

Comment: You need the dependencies listed here https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv/#getting-groovycsv in your classpath

Comment: Ok so i have added the groovycsv jar file i downloaded into my external libraries.

This resolved the error with the xlson.

I have ran it again and i get this error

Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added OpenCSV (as listed in that list of dependencies)?

Comment: I cant add it, i have downloaded the file but cant find where to add it in intellij

Comment: Just download http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.jar and add it to your classpath as you did with the groovycsv jar file

Comment: Managed to add it... new error~

Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: This script or class could not be run.
It should either:
- have a main method,
- be a JUnit test or extend GroovyTestCase,
- implement the Runnable interface,
- or be compatible with a registered script runner. Known runners:
  * <none>
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: This script or class could not be run.
It should either:
- have a main method,
- be a JUnit test or extend GroovyTestCase,
- implement the Runnable interface,
- or be compatible with a registered script runner. Known runners:
  * <none>

Comment: at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Comment: You are trying to run this as a script?  I converted it so it fitted in to your code example above...  I added a `main` block to the code in my answer so you can run it as a standalone program

Comment: Thanks! were getting closer
`code`
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Job
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Job
 at com.xlson.groovycsv.PropertyMapper.propertyMissing(PropertyMapper.groovy:52)
 at com.xlson.groovycsv.PropertyMapper.getProperty(PropertyMapper.groovy)
 at com.navis.extension.tee.CSVtoXML$_execute_closure1_closure2_closure3_closure4_closure5.doCall(tim.groovy:23)
 at com.navis.extension.tee.CSVtoXML$_execute_closure1_closure2_closure3_closure4.doCall(tim.groovy:22)
 at com.navis.extension.tee.CSVtoXML$_execute_closure1_closure2_closure3.doCall(tim.groovy:21)

Comment: `code`

at com.navis.extension.tee.CSVtoXML$_execute_closure1_closure2.doCall(tim.groovy:20)
 at com.navis.extension.tee.CSVtoXML.execute(tim.groovy:17)
 at com.navis.extension.tee.CSVtoXML$execute.call(Unknown Source)
 at com.navis.extension.tee.tim.run(tim.groovy:39)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

`code`

Comment: Is your CSV the same as the example you posted in the question?

Comment: And line 23 is `job( line[ 'Job' ] )` isn't it?  Can you save it as `CSVtoXML.groovy` rather than `tim.groovy`?  Might make a difference

Comment: `code` 

One of the classes is an explicit generated class using the class statement, the other is a class generated from the script body based on the file name. Solutions are to change the file name or to change the class name.
 @ line 14, column 1.
   public class CSVtoXML extends GroovyApi {
   ^

Comment: I have no idea what you've done :-(  You have two classes in that file both called the same thing?

Comment: Hi Tim,

I have put the current code and the current error in the original post at the bottom just to check i havent done anything stupid.

Comment: @Matt the `main` method needs to be inside the class definition (as in my answer), you've got it outside so Groovy sees a Script and an inner class, both called the same

Comment: I have added the main method inside the class and now i am back to the job error (i think), i have updated the current code adn current error in the original post at the bottom of it.

Comment: Can you add `println line` after the line `csvParser.each { line ->` and before the line `row {` and see what it prints out?

Comment: Tim!! we have a line!

Still getting the same error underneith the line though.

Code and Error updated..

Comment: What does it look like?  It should be a Map with `Job` as a key

Comment: Its just a line above the error, i have put it above in the orignal post current error section

Comment: @Matt is the file `tab` separated (as in your question) or comma `,` separated?

Comment: @Matt my guess is it is comma separated.  Change `separator:'\t'` to `separator:','`

Comment: Hi Tim, just in each tab as per screenshot 
[Screenshot Link](http://s21.postimg.org/8q47p5lgn/timsnip.png)

Comment: Ahhh, but Excel will hide the separator in the file when you imported the CSV, have a look at the actual `C:/convert/CRR.csv` file in notepad or something

Comment: Bingo! Right i have looked and it was comma seperated and i changed the seperator value to ',' this now outputs all three lines but gives a different error!

ive put it in the current error it has two lines which are very long!

Comment: @Matt Right...that's caused because groovy is using a different version of an XML library to one you have in your classpath...  Do you have something like xalan in your classpath?  Hopefully you added it for your initial tests, and it can be easily removed?

Comment: I have now deleted the xalan.jar from my library and ran it again, we now have less errors !!
`code
Job: JOB0001, Type: Circle, Cntr Number: 12
Job: JOB0002, Type: Square, Cntr Number: 13
Job: JOB0003, Type: Cube, Cntr Number: 15`
cont...

Comment: `code

Caught: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
 at com.navis.extension.tee.CSVtoXML.execute(CSVtoXML.groovy:17)
 at com.navis.extension.tee.CSVtoXML$execute.call(Unknown Source)
 at com.navis.extension.tee.CSVtoXML.main(CSVtoXML.groovy:34)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)`

Comment: Here are all the Jars i have in the class path i think?
[Link to Jars](http://s27.postimg.org/ujxzkci03/Jars.png)

Comment: wowsers!  I think that's all the jars ;-) *faint* can you make sure you've refreshed your dependencies?  I'm a bit stumped now... :-/

Comment: Hi Tim, how would i go about refreshing dependencies in intellij?

I also noticed the error is saying a Xalan is not found and this is the jar that i deleted?

Comment: No idea, I don't use intellij :-(  Maybe add the jar back in if it's required elsewhere in the project?  This is usually a conflict between xml-api, but if you require that for something else, I guess you're in dependency hell and it's going to be a struggle to do things the quick groovy way :-(

Comment: I am reloading the project in intelliJ and reloading all the libraries as i feel this may help starting with a fresh library.

i will update you when this is done.

Thanks for all your help so far, i have only been actively using groovy for 2 weeks! Massively struggling.

Comment: Right loaded everything back and ran it, get the three lines from the csv and the error i have put in the current error at the top.

Comment: It's not a Groovy error as far as I can see, it's a classpath collision/ommission.  Can you try removing `XmlUtil.serialize(` and the final `)` to see if it's `XmlUtil` that's struggling?

Comment: TIM!!! no errors!

Job: JOB0001, Type: Circle, Cntr Number: 12
Job: JOB0002, Type: Square, Cntr Number: 13
Job: JOB0003, Type: Cube, Cntr Number: 15
null

How can i get this too export it in xml? do i need to change the println part to print xml?

Comment: Lets try writing to a file...  Updated my answer

Comment: Hi Tim,

I tried the code you updated above but it brought back some errors, i think this is because there are some things missing from it from the one that worked last... anyway i had a go at modifying the working code and i have got as far as it creating the xml file but it is blank and everythign i try to add after is giving me an error i will update the current code in the first patr with where im at with it.

Comment: You've got printlns in odd places and you're not calling writeLine... compare it with the code at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Ah i didnt update the code properly!

Right i have added in the write line and took out the println's from the two new file lines.

not im getting an output still in the results, nothing in the xml file and an error.

Latest code and error above!

So close!

Comment: TIM!! i think ive done it!! i changed w.writeln to w.println and its working i think!

Comment: Woo! And just in time for a Friday evening beer! ;-)

Comment: Your a legend!!

Can the `def csvParser = parseCsv( r , speerator: ',')` line be used to ignore blank rows?

Comment: Just wrap an `if( line.size() > 0 )` round the `row {` block :-)  Have fun! (what an epic!) ;-)

Comment: Fun is not the word i would use to describe Groovy!

How can i wrap this if statement around the row? it keeps erroring when i try!

Comment: Updated the answer.  Seriously though, compare your original code with the working Groovy code and consider which is more fun ;-)  We're just having issues with the complexity of the classpath you are stuck with.  Heh, when I started this, I expected a quick resolution ;-)

Comment: Its fun because it is nearly working! I didnt expect this to ever be completed this month never mind a quick resolution.

Ive already wrapped the row with the linesize if statement and i get an error above..

Comment: Updated my answer...  This would be so much quicker if we were in the same room ;-)

Comment: Morning Tim! Tried the `if( line.size() > 0 )` in many different ways and tried with your updated answer above, keep getting various errors. Also tried using if row.size to no avail

Comment: @Matt morning! ;-)  Wish this was paying me by the hour ;-) hahaha..  Try:  `if( line.values.size() > 1 )`

Comment: Tim i'll pay you in beers if your ever up this neck of the woods!

Ok so that code runs, no errors, but doesnt actually do anything.

I have updated the current code to show what i've done, i also tried with `> 0` & `!=0` with no luck.

Comment: Does it print the lines out?

Comment: Yeh everything is same as having th code without the `if( line.values.size() > 1 ){` line in, same lines printed and same xml file contents output

Comment: That's good no?  The `if` should just skip blank lines in the CSV?  Or are blank lines included?

Comment: The blank lines are still included, screenshot here [Link to examplee](http://s14.postimg.org/5kcrpy7ap/xmlout.png)

Comment: Ahhh, you mean you have lines with no data, but they still have commas separating the blanks?  ie:  `,,,,,,`? Right, you'll need to change `if( line.values.size() > 1 ){` to `if( line[ 'Job' ] ) {`... THat will throw out any line with a blank Job column

Comment: Tim you genious!! Where can i even find this information, i do google each of these problems but groovy resources of information seems limited!

One last little thing if i have addition information above the beggining of the data i want in excel how can i get it to ignore it/start at the correct line, [Screenshot example](http://s17.postimg.org/8680urepr/ADDITIONAL.png)

Comment: Eurg...  That's a rather horrible one...  You could read the lines until you get a header style line, and then start the CSV parser passing this list of header names in to the parser.  Or you could pass the `columnNames` to the parseCsv method.  or if it's always that length of horrible header, you could read that many lines before starting the parser?

Comment: Could i get it to start when it finds the word job (the first column header)?

Comment: So long as no-one has any of that meta data starting with `Job,`

Comment: Yeh the first header will be Job always

Comment: Yeah, but you might have `Job` in one of the preceding lines :-/

Comment: Just confirmed there will never be a preceding Job on its own.

Could the parameter only look for Job rather than jobxxx, xxxjob, xxjobxx etc?

Comment: Sorry, just did a quick update, so I've you looked before, try it again now ;-)

Comment: Had a go with that one...

`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\...\CSVtoXML.groovy: 33: The current scope already contains a variable of the name line
 @ line 33, column 48.
                  csvParser.each { line ->
                                 ^

1 error`

Comment: Updated... SOrry about that :-/

Comment: works but values are in the wrong columns and some are blank when they shouldnt be...

`-<row><job>MT7090773</job><type/><cntr>40' High Cube</cntr><date/><bref/><comm/><weig>31-Oct-13</weig><spci/></row>`

Comment: Updated to print tokenized and size, what does that say?

Comment: Same output as previous comment

Comment: The println writes XML?

Comment: The xml file is created and the data is put in as above, just under the wrong headers

Comment: I added 2 println statements to the code to print the tokenized result and the size of it... Do they get printed?

Comment: Ohh my appologies, Yes 8...

`[Job, Type, Cntr Number, Date, Booking Ref, Commodity, Weight, Special Instructions]
8

Process finished with exit code 0
`

Comment: Try that then: https://gist.github.com/timyates/6460361cae39e59f7ffe I turned off `autodetect` so it should default to `,` for separator and `"` for quote char

Comment: Try that one, I have added back in `println line` so you can see what each line contains as it processes it

Comment: would chnaging the token size make any difference?

Comment: I have no idea...  It should work...  Can you post the actual (up to 3 lines of data) CSV you're trying to read so I can test rather than guess?  Screenshots of Excel aren't enough in this case, and pasting from excel as in the question doesn't give enough info either :-(  Just the first 20 lines of `CRR.csv` so it's got the header block, the column names and a couple of lines of data would help immeasurably ;-)

Comment: Why is everything double comma `,,` delimited?

Comment: You can't use double commas with OpenCSV

Comment: Theres double commas because there are columns with nothing in and also there are some columns that only have a header but nothing else.

if you use the previous code above (Current code 4/2/14) and then delete the top 18? rows (so the headers are at the top) it works fine.

just trying to get it to work when i have the extra lines at the top before the headers start.

Comment: Try changing: `def tokenized = spool.tokenize( ',' )` to `def tokenized = spool.split( ',' ).toList()`

Comment: Chnage that in the orignal code above or in the latest revision from github?

Comment: Tim!!! that works perfect with both csv's with stuff at the top before the headers and csv's with just headers!!

Thank you soo much for all your help, and patiance!

Your kind of a legend around here now! Everyone knows about Tim!

Comment: Lol :-)  No worries, glad we got to the bottom of it!  Keep my name in mind if ever you see me applying for a job ;-)  Good luck!

Comment: FYI Q: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303045/2641576 A: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303262/2641576

Comment: Hehe, got a warm feeling inside! Thanks, and again glad I could help :-)